# Derivation of entropy inequality for scalar conservation laws from viscous equation - discontinuous or infinite integrand

Tags: integration, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, continuity

I am self-studying *Numerical Methods for Conservation Laws* by LeVeque. I have a question about the derivation of the entropy inequality for the convex scalar conservation law
$$
u_t+f(u)_x=0\tag{1}
$$
which allows us to select unique weak solutions. I am sure that my question has been answered somewhere on stack exchange, but I haven't been able to express the mathematical verbiage that would allow me to find it.

**Background**

Let $\eta(u)$ be our "entropy" function which satisfies a conservation law of the form

$$
\eta(u)_t+\psi(u)_x=0
$$

where $\psi(u)$ is some "entropy flux" function. Assume that both $\eta(u)$ and $\psi(u)$ are convex. Multiplying (1) by $\eta'(u)$, we have
$$
\eta'(u)u_t+\eta'(u)f'(u)u_x=0
$$
from which we infer $\psi'(u)=\eta'(u)f'(u)$. Since we care about weak solutions admitting initial data with discontinuities in $u$, we consider the viscous equation for (1) as $\epsilon \to 0$.
$$
u_t+f(u)_x=\epsilon u_{xx}
$$
From which we can write
$$
\eta(u)_t+\psi(u)_x=\epsilon\eta'(u)u_{xx}
$$
Manipulating the right-hand side, we have
$$
\eta(u)_t+\psi(u)_x=\epsilon(\eta'(u)u_x)_x-\epsilon \eta''(u)u_x^2
$$
Now, consider a rectangle $[x_1,x_2] \times [t_1,t_2]$ where $u(x,t)$ has some discontinuity in the limiting solution as $\epsilon \to 0$.
$$
\int_{t_1}^{t_2}\int_{x_1}^{x_2} \eta(u)_t+\psi(u)_x dxdt = \epsilon \int_{t_1}^{t_2}\int_{x_1}^{x_2} (\eta'(u)u_x)_x dxdt -\epsilon \int_{t_1}^{t_2}\int_{x_1}^{x_2} \eta''(u)u_x^2 dxdt
$$
LeVeque writes

> As $\epsilon \to 0$, the first term on the right hand side vanishes. (This is clearly true if $u$ is smooth at $x_1$ and $x_2$, and can be shown more generally.) The other term, however, involves integrating $u_x^2$ over $[x_1,x_2] \times [t_1,t_2]$. If the limiting weak solution is discontinuous along a curve in this rectangle, then this term will not vanish in the limit.

The entropy condition for weak solutions
$$
\eta(u)_t+\psi(u)_x\leq 0
$$
follows.

**Question**

Can you help me understand why
$$
\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\left[\epsilon \int_{t_1}^{t_2}\int_{x_1}^{x_2} (\eta'(u)u_x)_x dxdt\right]=0
$$
but
$$
\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\left[\epsilon \int_{t_1}^{t_2}\int_{x_1}^{x_2} \eta''(u)u_x^2 dxdt\right]\neq 0
$$

Related:

- [Burgers' equation - Integrate discontinuity over rectangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3208435/burgers-equation-integrate-discontinuity-over-rectangle)
- [Integral form of the conservation law $u_t + f(u)_x=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3174583/integral-form-of-the-conservation-law-u-tfu-x-0)